# jQuery UI datepicker as "year calendar"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to get a full year calendar from `jQuery UI datepicker`, where I can interact with weeks rather than days.

I already found how to do the weekly part, but now I would like to display the full year, for a result similar to this :
[image]

I managed to add the 12 months, using the `numberOfMonths: 12`, but how can I set them display as a grid? I tried to set a width to the container, but it doesn't do anything.

For the starting month, I find on an other topic that I can change default date to 1st January adding `defaultDate: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0,1)`. This indeed make the months starting on January, but it also move the current day selection to 1st January... I would prefer, if someone knew a way to keep the current day as default selection.

Then for the previous/next button, is it possible to make them changing year in stead of month ? Else I think I may cheat, by adding an event handler to click 12 times instead of 1.

Finally, I would like to move the next button back to the third month like in the picture. It may not be very hard using CSS, so I'm just curious if there might be a function to do it more easily.

Here's a JSFiddle for my current code http://jsfiddle.net/AVZJh/2553/

Comment: Setting the width of `ui-datepicker` to `798px` (is exact number, but `800px` will be fine :)) will give you your grid. (seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/AVZJh/2614/)

Comment: that's the missing part for the grid, thanks :)

Comment: Here's the navigation arrows bit of your question, solved - http://jsfiddle.net/AVZJh/2615/

Comment: I just found the option `stepMonths:12` allowing me to move years in stead of months. Also for the grid, I found that I can say it as an array with `numberOfMonths: [4,3]`. The bonus is the style is adapt, for example border are well round, it cancel a small feature about showothermonth who add row on every next month on the line, and it move prev/next button as I want without CSS need. Now I'm only looking to make it start january without default selection on january. I'll do an answer to summarize if I manage to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found all the missing part, result : http://jsfiddle.net/AVZJh/2625/

Grid & mooving previous/next button was both done changing numberOfMonths to an array : `numberOfMonths: [4,3]`

Previous/next switching year in stead of month was done adding `stepMonths:12`

Starting at january without changing default date was done adding `showCurrentAtPos: new Date().getMonth()`

Comment: Good stuff mate, no hacks, flaky workarounds or css overrides +1

Comment: yeah, I should have read the API doc better before asking... anyway, hope it'll help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [AnyTime](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/). It has all the features you ask for.

Comment: I'm not against using an other library. It's just that I already used jQuery UI so I had some experience before working with it. Also most topic I found when looking for info was using it. About AnyTime, I read option list on your link, but doesn't find anything who could help me... grid ? display 12 months ? no overlay to simulate a "select week"